# OpenMP Performance impact: private directive vs. declaring variable inside for construct

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

Performance wise, which of the following is more efficient?

Assigning in the master thread and copying the value to all threads:

```
int i = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(i)
for( ; i < n; i++){
    ...
}
```

Declaring and assigning the variable in each thread

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ...
}
```

Declaring the variable in the master thread but assigning it in each thread.

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ...
}
```

It may seem a silly question and/or the performance impact may be negligible. But I'm parallelizing a loop that does a small amount of computation and is called a large number of times, so any optimization I can squeeze out of this loop is helpful.

I'm looking for a more low level explanation and how OpenMP handles this.

For example, if parallelizing for a large number of threads I assume the second implementation would be more efficient, since initializing a variable using `xor` is far more efficient than copying the variable to all the threads

Comment: Did you try measuring it, or are you asking us to do that for you?

Comment: I did not measure it, but I do not seek an answer in numbers, I seek a more low level answer.

Comment: This question would be more interesting if you *had* tried to measure it and then asked the results to be explained.

Comment: The first version is not a valid OpenMP code. The other two versions are equivalent and most likely would result in the same assembly code being generated for the extracted OpenMP region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much of a difference in terms of performance among the 3 versions you presented, since each one of them is using `#pragma omp parallel for`. Hence, OpenMP will automatically assign each for iteration to different threads. Thus, variable `i` will became private to each thread, and each thread will have a different range of for iterations to work with. The variable `'i'` was automatically set to private in order to avoid race conditions when updating this variable. Since, the variable `'i'` will be private on the parallel for anyway, there is no need to put **private(i)** on the `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Nevertheless, your first version will produce an error since OpenMP is expecting that the loop  right underneath of `#pragma omp parallel for` have the following format:

`for(init-expr; test-expr;incr-expr)`

inorder to precompute the range of work.

> The for directive places restrictions on the structure of all
>   associated for-loops.  Specifically, all associated for-loops must
>   have the following canonical form:
>
> for (init-expr; test-expr;incr-expr) structured-block ([OpenMP Application Program Interface](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) pag. 39/40.)

**Edit**: I tested your two last versions, and inspected the generated assembly. Both version produce the same assembly, as you can see -> [version 2](http://codepaste.net/4o4nnc) and [version 3](http://codepaste.net/istiz2).